# Elements skipped when calling extract in a loop

Tags: python, html, loops, beautifulsoup

I'm using `extract` to remove HTML elements in a loop, but it's causing elements to be skipped.

For example,

```
data = """<div><p class="1">1</p><p class="2">2</p><p class="3">3</p></div>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
div = soup.div
for p in div.contents: # or use for p in div.children:, with the same result
    print(p)
    if '2' in p.attrs['class']:
        p.extract()
    print(p)
    print("\n")
```

We can see from the output below that the `<p class="3">3</p>` was not printed.

```
<p class="1">1</p>
<p class="1">1</p>

<p class="2">2</p>
<p class="2">2</p>
```

However, I can see that the div was modified after the loop ended:

```
div
<div><p class="1">1</p><p class="3">3</p></div>
```

Why didn't the third element print?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `.extract`, the `div.contents` list is modified and the length is shortened by 1. The next element then becomes the current element and is skipped when the iterator moves forward. In general, avoid modifying lists while iterating through them.

One solution is to copy `div.contents` for iteration when you plan to extract elements. The element objects will still refer to the original `div.contents` list, so calling `p.extract` will still modify the original but won't upset the ordering of the aliased list that's being iterated through.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """<div><p class="1">1</p><p class="2">2</p><p class="3">3</p></div>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
div = soup.div

for p in div.contents[:]:
#                    ^~~
    print(p)

    if '2' in p.attrs['class']:
        p.extract()

    print(p, "\n")

print("after:", div.contents)
```

Output:

```
<p class="1">1</p>
<p class="1">1</p>

<p class="2">2</p>
<p class="2">2</p>

<p class="3">3</p>
<p class="3">3</p>

after: [<p class="1">1</p>, <p class="3">3</p>]
```